# Reading multiple band image with C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, libtiff.net, satellite-image

I'm trying to read images with multiple bands (multispectral images). A normal image normally has 3 bands (RGB). I learned that certain type of images (eg: satellite images) can have more than 3 bands, like infrared and etc.

I know how to read a normal image with `Bitmap` class from `System.Drawing` and get its color values per pixel in Red, Green, and Blue values.

Using C# how can I read the other bands? I have found few libraries but couldn't understand how they work (not even sure if they are related). LibTiff.net is one of them (it sounds promising since the multispectral image extension is .tiff) though I couldn't find any reference for 'bands' in an image.

Comment: It depends on exactly how these images are formatted internally, and, more importantly... how you want to display them. Monitors are generally not suitable for emitting infrared or ultraviolet spectrum.

Comment: There are standard formats for these images. When showing these kind of images they let you only select 3 bands, assign them to RGB bands in a certain order and omit the rest of the bands. This way you can analyse multispectral images visually.

Comment: tiff images are a bit of a mess... the name is jokingly said to mean  "Thousands of Incompatible File Formats". As the joke implies, you're never sure exactly how an image is stored inside a .tiff file, and it makes manipulation of .tiff images a nightmare.